# Flutter not pointing me to the line throwing an error

Tags: android-studio

Before in my android studio and flutter project, if I have an error showing like this image below [image: Error Example]

When I click on the file path throwing the error, it takes me to the exact line throwing the error in the file, but since when I reinstall android studio, when I click the file path throwing the error, it always takes me to line 1 of the file.

Is there a way I can resolve this issue?